# String which contains Byte Array in incorrect form into String

Tags: c#, string, bytecode

I've a question concerning the following problem:

```
// input-String (including four bytes) : d131dd02...
// transform Bytes-String in String (this Works!) manually:
String message = ((char)0xd1).ToString() + ((char)0x31).ToString() + ((char)0xdd).ToString() + ((char)0x02).ToString()+ ....
```

I want to write a function which transforms me the above given Input String in the correct format automatically.
I started to write some code but it doesn't work because I have no idea how i've to do it.

```
if(checkBox1.Checked== true)
{
   String message = null;
   char[] bufferArray = textBox1.Text.ToArray();
   MessageBox.Show(bufferArray.Length.ToString());
   for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.TextLength / 2; i+=2)
   {
      String buffer=("0" + "x" + bufferArray[i] + bufferArray[i+1]);
      message += ((char)buffer.ToString();
   }
   richTextBox1.Text = getMd5Hash(message);
   richTextBox2.Text = MD5HashBerechnen(message).ToLower();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the output you're getting? ie: what does "message" contain when you're code is done?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this question correctly if you gave both expected input and output, and what you are really getting as output.

Comment: Input for example: d1 as a string; expected Output: String message = ((char)0xd1).ToString; Unfortunately I have currently no computer with me to provide you with more Data. I want to convert any string which includes Bytes in Text format into a normal String in the format given by the Code above --> ((char)0xd1).tostring()

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding_methods.aspx) class.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bufferArray));
```

Comment: ASCII doesn't handle some of the example bytes, but other encodings (such as the windows ansi 1252) do.

Comment: @Jimmy: very true, I was just using it as an example, and why I linked to the Encoding class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just get rid of the " / 2".

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because in the first case you are casting a number to char, in the second you are casting a string to a char.

`0xd1` is not the same as `"0xd1"`

Comment: So how do i convert the Input String into a Number, to get the Same result?

Comment: You can use [Convert.ToByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk.aspx).